# ng2-boostrap datePicker seems to overwrite ngModel

Tags: datepicker, angular, ng2-bootstrap

I'm utilizing the ng2-bootstrap datePicker, and whether I leave the initial value undefined, or if I use the initDate, I get an unexpected behavior.
Right away upon loading the page the variable bound to ngModel of the directive, in my case:

[(ngModel)]="campaign.startDate"

campaign.startDate logs as:
FIRST - today, or an assigned value if I set it arbitrarily in the ngOnInit
THEN - takes on the value I have assigned it once my request comes back with a new value
THEN - today

I have no idea what triggers that third step, and as far as I can tell it's not coming from my code, but due to the 2 way binding, the datePicker itself for some reason is assigning it a value of "today"

TS

```
getCampaign(id:number){
    this._campaignService.getCampaignById(id)
        .subscribe(
            campaign => {
                this.campaign = campaign;
            }
        )
}
ngOnInit(){
    this.campaign = {
        startDate:new Date()
    }
    this.getCampaign(4);
}
```

and HTML

```
<datepicker [(ngModel)]="campaign.startDate" [showWeeks]="true"></datepicker>
```

Comment: Can you produce problem using plunker?

Comment: I created a plunkr to try to reproduce your problem: https://plnkr.co/edit/z6w52Z2K8EX4M6zzWTku?p=preview. The third step isn't executed... Can you see something different with your code?