# How to use bootstrap/jquery in Angular2

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, angular

How is the best way to use a bootstrap plugin like Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker in Angular2?

I use jspm in my setup and have installed Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker. The I include the javascript in my Component:

```
import { datepicker } from 'Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker';
```

In AfterViewInit I have tried to add the .datetimepicker() to the html element like this:

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
      var elm = <HTMLDivElement>document.getElementById('datetimepicker1');
      elm.datetimepicker();
    }
```

But this is not working. How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Can you provide a plunker?

Comment: How about `$(elm).datetimepicker();` ?

Comment: you  want to use datePIcker in angular2 ? i have another custom date picker if you want ill post it as answer.

Comment: @PardeepJain I would really like to see the picker if you like :)

Comment: @DNRN i have posted answer check it out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of leaving a comment I prefer to post this as answer *(as demanded by @DNRN)* because it may helpful to someone else in the future.

You test the solution without having to import any extra files, I have posted a solution online using the datepicker component and bootflat as a styling framework as well as a [date picker library](https://github.com/MrPardeep/Angular2-DatePicker) or for more info you can [refer to this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34788543/how-to-use-date-picker-in-angular-2/34930568#34930568)...

[image]
[image]

Here are few More best articles/libraries for datepicker

- https://github.com/kekeh/mydatepicker
- https://github.com/jkuri/ng2-datepicker
- http://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/calendar

Answer (score 0):

I have just created a directive for `Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker` in Angular 2: https://github.com/atais/ng2-eonasdan-datetimepicker

It is currently in very early stages but hopefully it should meet your requirements.

Regarding your question, I have managed to instantiate the calendar element with the help of jQuery:

```
import * as $ from 'jquery';

constructor(el: ElementRef, renderer: Renderer) {
    let $parent = $(el.nativeElement.parentNode);
    this.dpElement = $parent.hasClass('input-group') ? $parent : $(el.nativeElement);
}

ngOnInit(): void {
    this.dpElement.datetimepicker(this.options);
    this.dpElement.data('DateTimePicker').date(this.date);
}
```