# Angular2 update Directive Input

Tags: jquery, angular, angular2-directives

I have an Angular2 Directive which sets the maxDate of my DatePicker like this.

```
@Directive({
    selector: '[maxDate]'
})

export class MaxDateDirective {
    private domElement: any;
    @Input() set maxDate(max: any) {
        if (max) {
            $(this.domElement).data("DateTimePicker").maxDate(max);
        }
    }

    constructor(private element: ElementRef, private renderer: Renderer) {
        this.domElement = element.nativeElement;
    }
}
```

In my component I've dateFrom and dateTo like this.

```
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="label-control">{{'START_DATE' | translate}}</label>
                            <input id="owner_start_date" name="owner_start_date" type="text" class="form-control datepicker" [(ngModel)]="filters.lastWeek"
                                [maxDate]="filters.today" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="label-control">{{'END_DATE' | translate}}</label>
                            <input id="owner_end_date" name="owner_end_date" type="text" class="form-control datepicker" [(ngModel)]="filters.today"
                            />
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

So, my fromDate picker has this `[maxDate]="filters.today"`, which is bind to the `[(ngModel)]="filters.today"` of the toDate picker, but my `@Input() set maxDate(max: any)`is only triggering once. How can I check for updates on the model in the component from inside the Directive? I don't want to add code to the component, the Directive should be in charge of that logic, like the `$watch` in Angular1.

Answer (score 1):

You could utilize the Angular lifecycle hook [OnChanges](https://angular.io/api/core/OnChanges) within the `MaxDateDirective` that would allow you to "watch" for changes to the `@Input() set maxDate(max: any)` and react to them as needed, such as executing `maxDate()` with the new max date value. You would hook into `OnChanges` like this:

```
@Directive({
    selector: '[maxDate]'
})

export class MaxDateDirective implements OnChanges {
    private domElement: any;

    @Input() set maxDate(max: any) {
        if (max) {
            $(this.domElement).data("DateTimePicker").maxDate(max);
        }
    }

    constructor(private element: ElementRef, private renderer: Renderer) {
        this.domElement = element.nativeElement;
    }

    ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
        $(this.domElement).data("DateTimePicker").maxDate(changes.maxDate.currentValue);
    }
}
```

The object passed to the `ngOnChanges()` provides additional values that you could utilize such as previous value.

Here is a [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/pY2SUwdOa4N7GKNxtNeL) demonstrating at a simple level how that would look.

Hopefully that helps!

Comment: I've tried this, but the ngOnChanges is never triggering when I select a new value in the toDate picker...it's like the [maxDate]="filters.today" is not looking at the filters.today changes

Comment: If you put {{filters.today}} on the page, do you see the interpolated value change when you select a different date?

Comment: Yeah...the problem is that my datepicker isn't updating my ngModel. As soon as I fix it, I'll let you know. Thanks!

Comment: You could try lifecycle hook `DoCheck` to try detect the changes and selectively execute the jQuery DatePicker functionality and/or try flattening `filters.today` to just a separate class property `today` which should hopefully help with the change detection.

Comment: This is how I fix it. Thank you for your time!

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36087762/how-to-detect-bootstrap-datetimepicker-change-events-within-angular2