# Input value not updated with JQuery datepicker in Angular 7

Tags: jquery, angular, datepicker

I am using **Angular 7** with a **JQuery** datepicker : https://github.com/uxsolutions/bootstrap-datepicker

```
           <div class="col-lg-2">
              <div class="form-group">
                <div class="input-group">
                  <input class="form-control form-control-lg" data-provide="datepicker" data-date-language="fr" type="text" data-date-format="dd/mm/yyyy" placeholder="From" [(ngModel)]="from" name="from" />
                  <div class="input-group-append">
                    <span class="input-group-text"><i class="fa fa-calendar" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
```

But in the component, this value I receive in `this.from` is `undefined`..

```
export class SearchBarComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(
    private router: Router
  ) { }

  search: string;
  from: string;
  to: string;

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  onSubmit() {
    console.log(this.from)
  }
}
```

I do not want to use bundle like `ng-boostrap` or `ngx-boostrap` because I do not want to trick with the navbar to get it working. And I prefer to control the dependencies of Boostrap.

Is there a simple way to watch for changes of this input value please ? I did not find this answer clearly in the questions that can exist.

Comment: i am not sure if this bootstrap data-picker package is compatible with angular, maybe try other like ngx-bootstrap -> https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-bootstrap-datepicker

Comment: @Jake11 : Thanks, but as I said : `I do not want to use bundle like ng-boostrap or ngx-boostrap because I do not want to trick with the navbar to get it working. And I prefer to control the dependencies of Boostrap.`

Comment: I tried this answer that I did not see and it is working : https://stackoverflow.com/a/36090026/1699865

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `changeDate` event

```
ngOnInit() {
$('.datepicker').datepicker()
    .on("changeDate", function(date) {
        this.from = date;
    });
 }
```

[more info on events](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/stable/events.html#events)

Comment: Thanks a lot but I get this error : `ERROR TypeError: jquery__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_4__(...).datepicker is not a function`

Comment: make sure you load datepicker before your angular app

Comment: ya man, see this tutorial for the error https://medium.com/all-is-web/angular-5-using-jquery-plugins-5edf4e642969

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#data').datepicker({
    onSelect: (dateText: any, object: any) => {
        this.formulario.get('data').setValue(dateText);
    }
});
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please comment a bit what your code does. For more guidance see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer