# Datepicker with Angular 2 RC1

Tags: javascript, datepicker, angular, npm

Is there a datepicker which we can use with Angular 2 RC1

I can see ng2-datepicker is using angular2 RC1 but while installing it's looking for Angular 2 Beta.

Any Help.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Have a look at this: https://github.com/kekeh/mydatepicker

Comment: No it's using Angular 2 Beta

Answer (score 1):

Have a look here, using `angular2 RC.1`

> https://github.com/MrPardeep/Angular2-DatePicker

[image]

see also :

- [How to use date picker in Angular 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34930568/5043867)
- http://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/calendar

Comment: Hey Thanks for this,
But there is nothing about How to install 

I tried this
 "npm install Angular2-Bootflat-DatePicker"
and 
"npm install Angular2-DatePicker "

Both doesn't works

Comment: hey @ArunTyagi just fork/clone the repo, go inside the Angular2 datepicker folder, where your `package.json` exist, run command `npm install` than run command `gulp` .

Comment: or you can see `Getting Started` section of repo on github there, if found something amazing in datepicker just give start to motivate me ;-)

Comment: can't we install it as we install other plugin from npm ?

Comment: yeah you can just you have to run `npm install` as other repo's

Answer (score 1):

Try Calendar control from primeNG. This gives you any format of date & time.

Sample implementation looks like below-

1. Update package.json

   "primeng": "^1.0.0-beta.7",
   "primeui": "^4.1.10",
2. import Calendar from primeNG

   import { Calendar } from 'primeng/primeng';
3. Declare it in directives

   directives: [Calendar]
4. Use it in Component template

p-calendar [(ngModel)]="date1" dateFormat="mm/dd/yy" timeFormat="HH:mm">

You can find more format examples on - http://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/calendar