# PrimeNG Calendar error - JQuery is not defined

Tags: angular, primeng, primeng-calendar

I want to use [PrimeNG calendar](http://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/calendar) in my app. When I run the code, I get the error:

> ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined.

Other PrimeNG directives work fine. If I remove `<p-calendar>` the error disappears.

I have imported and included Calendar in my app. 
By the way I'm using the latest versions of angular, router and forms. Before that I had this [issue](https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/issues/549) and fixed it by updating form providers.

```
 <p-calendar [(ngModel)]="date"></p-calendar>
```

Stacktrace excerpt:

> ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
>           at Calendar.ngAfterViewInit (eval at  (http://localhost:8080/js/app.js:930:2), :44:90)
>           at DebugAppView._View_AddShipmentComponent0.detectChangesInternal (AddShipmentComponent.template.js:930:59)
>           at DebugAppView.AppView.detectChanges (eval at  (http://localhost:8080/js/vendor.js:716:2), :243:14)
>           at DebugAppView.detectChanges (eval at  (http://localhost:8080/js/vendor.js:716:2), :348:44)

Comment: If you don't have one, try including a reference to jQuery in your index.html.

Comment: `<p-calendar>` Dependencies are : `jQuery UI Datepicker and  DateTimePicker`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to add the dependencies:

```
<!-- Datetimepicker, Slider, Schedule -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon/1.6.1/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: this is so sad :(

Comment: Well, In the bright side the team is working to remove third party dependencies from calendar :)

Comment: Beta19 has a native calendar, not jquery based. http://blog.primefaces.org/?p=4149

Answer (score 4):

You can also add just this:

`<script src="node_modules/primeui/primeui-ng-all.min.js"></script>`

Or, if you're using the angular-cli like me you can `npm i primeui` and add this to your `angular-cli.json`:

`"scripts": ["../node_modules/primeui/primeui-ng-all.min.js"]`

**Update**

in `beta.19` The dependency of JQuery has been removed.

Reference: http://blog.primefaces.org/?p=4149