# Angular 6 material - how to get date and time from matDatepicker?

Tags: angular

I have this piece of code in my html:

```
<mat-form-field>
    <input matInput [matDatepicker]="myDatepicker" placeholder="Choose a date" [(ngModel)]="model.value" name="value">
    <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="myDatepicker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
    <mat-datepicker #myDatepicker></mat-datepicker>
</mat-form-field>
```

With this i'm able to get date with this format: `YYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss:millisZ`.

Using matDatepicker i'm able to select the date but i need after the date selection to select the time too.
Is possible to achieve this result using matDatepicker **ONLY**?
Thanks

Comment: Well if you are willing to use third-party datetime pickers you can try  this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/71742883/5374995 or https://www.npmjs.com/package/@handylib/ngx-datepicker

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No, as of now, it is not possible to choose `time` from `matDatePicker`. There is still an open issue on [github](https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/5648) regarding this feature.

Summary of the issue thread :

Alternatively you can use one of the following to have `dateTimePicker` for your project.

1. [MaterialTimeControl](https://github.com/SteveDunlap13/MaterialTimeControl) - Material Design with Angular Material, CDK, and Flex Layouts
2. [amazing-time-picker](https://github.com/casni14/amazing-time-picker) - Not built with Angular Material, but built to be compatible with it
3. [date-time-picker](https://danielykpan.github.io/date-time-picker/) - Not fully Material Design, but built with the CDK

Comment: It seems that i can't insert non-matInput elements in a mat-form-field! It's that possible? O.o"

Comment: Which element are you referring to?

Comment: Do you know if any of this is compatible with angular6, rxjs6 ?

Answer (score 1):

If you want a simple solution, then **`type="time"`** works. [polyfill](https://www.npmjs.com/package/time-input-polyfill) required for Safari and IE,

**Example:**

```
<mat-form-field>
  <input matInput type="time" class="bg-none" formControlName="_time" placeholder="Time">
</mat-form-field>
```

You will have to do the following to polyfill an Angular app

`npm i time-input-polyfill`

add the following line to **polyfill.ts** under `APPLICATION IMPORTS`

```
import 'time-input-polyfill';
```

Comment: Question was specifically regarding the use of matDatepicker..

Comment: Today it's [not possible](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51309204/234110) So I provided an alternative without matDatepicker for others who land here. Apologies, for offending you.

Comment: Not offended at all!  It's just the functionality in matDatepicker is pretty specific, and the proposed solution here doesn't really come close to meeting the same needs.

Answer (score 0):

Even though it's not perfect, nevertheless the mat date picker lets you select date AND time after that, no need for extra libraries, if you accept some compromise.

Here it is.

```
<mat-form-field>
    <input matInput
    required
    formControlName = "h_Ini"
    type="datetime-local"
    placeholder="Data Lezione"
    >
    <mat-datepicker></mat-datepicker>
</mat-form-field>
```

When you include type="datetime-local" this makes it for dates AND times.
The little problem I haven't solved yet is that since this comes with an in-built toggle (that's why there is not additional toggle specified) you can't include for the picker a values-filter.