# How to format the Date to British Date or US Date and get time from DatePicker

Tags: matblazor

New to MatBlazor below

```
 <MatDatePicker @bind-Value="@Date1"></MatDatePicker>
```

1. Want to learn how to get date, format the date and get the time
2. Does this one has time component?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

1. Just get the value from variable Date1 from your component.

Example :

```
<MatDatePicker @bind-Value="@Date1"></MatDatePicker>

@code{
var formattedValue = Date1.ToString("dd mm yyyy");
var dateValue = Date1.Date;
var timeValue = Date1.TimeOfDay;
}
```

2. As the current version, the control have implemented ToLocalTime() default.

Answer (score 0):

Please ask 1 question at a time.

MatDatePicker is based upon mat-datepicker
Best would to look into material design and the ui components for answers to your question

Even though it is for Angular, it gets close, for example look at [Angular 6 material: how to get date and time from matDatepicker?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51308613/angular-6-material-how-to-get-date-and-time-from-matdatepicker)